# Write a Google Earth in browser with webgl(three.js) and maps api, where to start?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I'm learning three.js, now I can write demos like a cube which could be moved by the mouse.
What I'd like to do next is a Google Earth in browser which will use Google Maps API to get the images and render them on an earth in the browser.
But I don't know where to start, I've seen the document of three.js but it just list the API names and parameters, without explain of what they do...
My question is, which part of three.js should I learn to accomplish what I want?

Comment: I can't give you a complete solution, but I can say you will definitely need to learn how to use LOD (Level of Detail), so you're only rendering what you see and not wasting resources. This would be a good exaple to demonstrate that concept http://spidergl.org/example.php?id=8

hope this at least gives you somewhere to start

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but were you looking into doing something like [Panedia](http://maps.panedia.com/) where the images update depending on user's location on the map?